# Is it possible to hide from the code a URL inside an iframe to avoid a user can modify the parameters?

Tags: url, hide, pentaho

I embed some pentaho reports in a web page and I pass some parameters to filter the data. I need than a user can't modify these parameters to avoid he can access to another data.

Is it possible to hide the URL from the code (or obfuscate it)?

Comment: Anything you do client-side can be hacked by anyone. If you want to protect your data the server that provides it must implement some sort of authentication and authorisation itself.

Comment: it's in the user's browser, so, no... there is absolutely NOTHING you can do to hide these. even if you put in place the most absolutely incredible uncrackable obfuscation on the raw code, they can simply switch over to the network tab and see what urls are being requested anyways.

Comment: Talking about normal users, not hackers. The only option would be to encrypt the parameters and decrypt them in the report, in order to get a bit of obfuscation. So the question is: Is it possible to do that with pentaho reports?

Comment: Yes. That is possible.

Comment: Even if it's possible... just don't. If you want to stop users from changing the parameter values, have data security in place in such way that even if they do change the parameters, the queries return empty resultsets. Otherwise you're just obfuscating stuff, not securing it. Pentaho allows you to define role based access to columns and rows in both Mondrian and Pentaho Metadata, that's what you should be doing.

Comment: The problem is that in my case that parameter defines a city and each user can only access to the data of their city. These cities are not fixed, but they can be added to the database all the time. So create a user and a role for each city is not an option. Furthermore, the schema should work without have to be modified. The only way I have found to accomplish this requirement is to use a parameter with the city and obtain that value from the database. Another option would be to pass the user id, name or whatever and obtain the city with a query.

Comment: @nsousa Although I don't know if I could do that in PRD. Working with CDE it would be possible, defining priorities, but in PRD I don't think. So, if the use of roles don't fit with my requirements, what options do I have?

Comment: Your best option is by creating a session variable that is called directly in the query, without the use of parameters. Remember that environment and session variables are accessible via PRD or CDE.

Comment: I can't figure out how I can do that. My web is running using xampp (where I store the session variables) and pentaho biserver is in another port. Then I use a iframe with a URL to access the report and I append a user and the password to this URL (but these are the same for everybody). I supposse that the session variable you are talking about is referred to a biserver session. And it's the same, the users are registered in my web and stored in the database so there isn't a pentaho user for each one of them. Pentaho it's something hidden for the client.

Comment: @nsousa Am I right or I miss anything?

Comment: if all your users use the same pentaho credentials... how will pentaho be able to tell them apart to filter out the data? Set up proper security to your application, then you can think about filtering the data.

Comment: General security doc: http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fconfig_ba_server%2Ftask_managing_users_and_roles.html ; Single sign-on doc: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0P0/150/010/060

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. There's a web in the which there is a section with the reports, and when you click on them, they are opened in a new tab, but embeded into an iframe. Then, the web admin has a section in the which he adds the users with a form. They don't want to modify nothing in pentaho, they just want to use the web. So all have default credentials with read permissions.

Comment: I know that you can't prevent the users to access the whole data, but with these requirements the only thing I can think about it's obfuscate the url and try to set an empty option if you access without a param value. I can imagine how to do that with CDE but no with PRD.

Comment: sorry, I'm not going to help you by suggesting an implementation that has gaping security holes. if you want to build something like that, you're on your own.